# Confusing read_table error in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read the [seeds dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/seeds) using pandas. When loading the file using:

```
df = pd.read_table("seeds_dataset.txt", header=None)
```

I get:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 8, saw 10
```

Now, for loading the file with excel, I needed to specify tab and space as delimiters at the same time, to correctly read the file at that line 8, something that can't be done with pandas (as far as I know). Sublime Text reads the file accurately directly.

I don't want to skip the bad lines with `error_bad_lines` as there is nothing wrong with them. I used also `lineterminator` with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the option "delim_whitespace".

```
df = pd.read_table("seeds_dataset.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace = True)
```

EDIT: more detailed explanation:

The method signature for `read_table` is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html).  It has all sorts of options, one of which is `sep`.  This defines the delimiter between fields, and its default is '\t' (tab).  One solution is to change the `sep` argument.  The python implementation of the pandas parser lets you use regex delimiters, so `sep = "\\s+"` would delimit on any amount of whitespace.  However, the C parser (which it looks like you're using from the error message) doesn't let you use regex.  It does have the `delim_whitespace` option, though, which fit your needs exactly!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain more why does using `delim_whitespace` works? I am more interested in knowing the origin of the issue